# How to find active docker images and volumes?

Tags: docker, docker-cli

I can see docker disk using the `docker system df` command:

```
$ docker system df
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          31        1         12.86GB   12.81GB (99%)
Containers      1         0         0B        0B
Local Volumes   25        1         17.24GB   17.19GB (99%)
Build Cache     244       0         6.249GB   6.249GB
```

The output shows one image and one volume are active. How can I find these active objects?

I don't think I have any active objects because `docker ps` displays no results. Perhaps these are internally managed docker objects?

Comment: what does `docker ps -a` display?

Comment: `docker ps -a` showed one container. I removed it using `docker rm <container-id>`. Now I'm seeing zero active objects. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker ps -a` solved the problem